Are split-ticket results a frequent occurrence?
Sometimes, there are Democrat down-ballot wins in a state (positions like governor, lieutenant governor, attorney general, secretary of state, etc.) but an overall win for Republican for the presidential vote in that state. For example, this happened in November 2024 in Pennsylvania, Wisconsin, Michigan and North Carolina.
I'm sure it's not uncommon for members of either party to have small wins here or there that don't align with the Presidential pick.
I would like to know if it has happened in the past, and if it's been both ways (R down-ballot, D president, or D down-ballot, R president).

@Jen with how much you've edited, you might as well have just asked your own question...

@nightsurfer no; I retained your question. I didn't change the question asked. What I edited was the commentary that was not the question. And the existing answer does not even engage with that extraneous "buzz", so the edit doesn't affect the validity of the existing answer.

@Jen or maybe consider you've entirely changed the background and reasoning for my question, and removed any personality from HOW i ask it. I started the question because there was so much buzz on social media about it, without any real sourcing or historical information. If there was something wrong with the question, then by all means, change it. But dropping the personality from it rubs me the wrong way.


Are split-ticket results a frequent occurrence?

Yes.
The 2020 election was a rare exception, with particularly low rates of split ticket voting, but even it had some. The medium term trend, prior to 2024, had been towards gradually falling rates of split-ticket voting, however.
The 2024 general election was more typical of the historical norm, in terms of rates of split ticket voting.
Usually, a candidate who wins a race in a jurisdiction or district that usually favors a candidate of a different major political party does so in either a U.S. Senate race, or an election for the chief elected official in the executive branch for a particular governmental body (such as a state or municipality). It is often driven by the individual distinctions of the candidates in that race from the typical candidates from a political party.
Sometimes, e.g., in the 2024 North Carolina Governor's race or Alabama electing a U.S. Senator who was a Democrat, this is driven by the candidate in the party that you would expect to win in that state being particularly bad. At other times, like Machin's U.S. Senate wins before he retired in what had become a GOP stronghold, or Romney's win for Governor of Massachusetts in a Democratic stronghold (both in prior years), it is driven by a candidate's reputation as a competent moderate.
Sometimes it is driven by a politician who sticks to an old party label even when the policies of the party in question drift over time from what they were when the politician first ran for elective office (e.g. in the case of Senator John McCain of Arizona in the later years of his U.S. Senate service as a Republican).

It can be argued that Manchin himself is an example of the "old party label" phenomenon. When he was elected governor of West Virginia (as a Democrat), the state was represented in the Senate by Democrats Robert Byrd (a seat that Manchin would eventually occupy) and Jay Rockefeller. Byrd's Democratic party would be unrecognizable today - he (Byrd) filibustered the Civil Rights Act. Manchin's time in the Senate was, in my reading of events, the last gasp of the southern wing of the Democratic party.

It depends on the office. It is common for red and blue states to have governors from the oppisite party (think Kentucky, North Carolina, New Hampshire, Vermont etc.) It's even more common for other statewide positions. When it comes to the federal election like for the senate it is considerably less common for voters to split their vote. In 2016 and 2020, there were 69 Senate races. Only one person, Susan Collins in 2020, managed to win a senate seat as a member of one party (Republican) while the other party (Democrat) won the white house in her state

I'd note that this is a rather restrictive definition of split-ticket voting. If the Presidential candidate from a major party and a U.S. Senate candidate from the same party get a very different percentage of the vote in the same election, even if the same party wins both races in that state, there is still split-ticket voting, just not enough of it to secure a different result (which in states that lean strongly towards one party would require an extreme degree of it). See, e.g., UT in 2020, the state cast its electoral votes for Trump but with big % to a third-party candidate.
